# Getting a syntax error when checking if a value is type Integer

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to validate that the customer's age is either empty or is a number. Here's my code:

```
json["customers"].each do |customer|
  faults = Array.new
  puts customer["name"]
  if customer["name"].length < 5 || customer["name"].length > 20
    if customer["email"].to_s.empty?
      faults.push "email"
    end
    if !customer["age"].to_s.empty? && !customer["age"].is_a? Integer
      fault.push "age"
    end
    if customer["password"].length < 8
      fault.push "password"
    end
    puts faults faults.push "name"
  end
```

Am I doing this right?

I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
!customer["age"].is_a? Integer
                              ^
```

This should be a simple syntax error, but I can't figure it out. Am I using `Integer` correctly here?

Comment: It's a _syntax error_, i.e. Ruby cannot parse your code. It has nothing to do with missing includes.

Comment: @sawa was referring more to the main idea of my code. You're right it's obvious there's a syntax error. But my usage of the phrase was referring more the approach I was taking to solve the issue. Not sure what value your comment is contributing frankly...

Comment: Quick tip for range checking: `(5..20).include?(customer['name'].length)`

Comment: When dealing with JSON data you may want to avoid hard type checks with `is_a?`. It's not uncommon for people to inadvertently supply numerical data as strings, and converting these strings to integers via `to_i` is trivial. If you do want to have a strict validation process then look at [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org) as a standardized solution to this problem. It's a JSON file like an XML DTD which you can publish as a spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with parentheses

```
if !customer["age"].to_s.empty? && !customer["age"].is_a?(Integer)
```

Comment: You're a genius. God bless and thanks. Why do I need the parentheses?

Comment: Because without the parser can't disambiguate what you're trying to do

Comment: @CapnJack `foo bar && baz` could be `foo(bar && baz)` or `foo(bar) && baz`

Comment: wait @Stefan are you saying that I could do `customer["age"](.to_s.empty? && .is_a?(Integer)`?

Comment: `if !customer["age"].to_s.empty? && (!customer["age"].is_a? Integer)` should work as well

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @CapnJack no, I just wanted to provide an example for an ambiguous syntax. It was meant as an answer to _"Why do I need the parentheses?"_ – because Ruby doesn't understand your code otherwise. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Stefan oh I see now. That clears a lot up. Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it : )